# Routing between interfaces

Tags: iptables, routing

Can't figure this one out. I have 3 hosts.

```
HostA: eth0: 10.10.80.5
HostB: eth0: 10.10.80.4, tun0:10.9.0.1
HostC: tun0: 10.9.0.74
```

I'm trying to reach port 7000 on HostC, from HostA. HostB becomes the routing problem. So far...:

```
HostA ---> HostB = OK

HostB ---> HostC = OK

HostC ---> HostB = OK

HostC ---> HostA = OK

HostA ---> HostC = Nothing
```

I've **enabled ipv4 forwarding on HostB** with **sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward**. I'm using iptables for this. Here are my current rules: Note: LANIF=eth0, WANIF=tun0

HostB:

```
$IPTABLES -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $LANIF -j MASQUERADE
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $LANIF -o $WANIF -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $WANIF -o $LANIF -j ACCEPT

$IPTABLES -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $WANIF -j MASQUERADE
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $WANIF -o $LANIF -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $LANIF -o $WANIF -j ACCEPT
```

HostA:

```
Route Table:
10.9.0.74       10.10.80.4      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
```

I have enabled logging on HostB to see the traffic and everything is routing correctly except for when I try to initiate a connection from HostA ---> HostC. It looks like it is not translating the between the two interfaces.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enable ipv4 forwarding (routing) in the OS.  Check the status of forwarding:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
```

if it says `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0` then edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`

change:

`net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0`

to read

`net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

Comment: sorry, its a bit hidden in the details (edited) but this is configured already

Comment: Okay. I was going off of the statement that you are using IPTables for this.

Comment: Do you have a rule that is accepting dport 7000?  If not, it won't hit on your established,related state.

Comment: Yes, HostB accepts connections from HostA on port 7000 as well. This is done in azure, so I'm thinking its something with their pre-configured routing tables

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed that it was a Azure routing issue. Although many won't have the same problems, I added a default route and a next hop in order to forward traffic out the correct interface.